# IIS: prevent new directories over FTP

Tags: iis, configuration, ftp

At work we're using plain vanilla FTP by IIS to accept images from photographers.
Each user has a folder, and each user-folder has ready-made folders for each print format we offer.

Prints are ordered by uploading JPG's into one or more of the folders, and a daily schedule checks the folders to place the digital print orders.

This scheduled job disregards any folders that have been created by the user, also those created in one of the format-folders.

Is there a way to configure IIS to disallow creating directories of your own? We've clearly marked in the documentation that the image files need to be directly under a format-folder, but it would be nice if new or distracted users get an appropriate error through the FTP client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NTFS permissions, can be set to allow users to create files, but not folders.

Navigate to the root of all the users virtual directory's actual location. Simply edit the ACL to deny the user-group(1) the ability to "Create Folders/ Append Data". This will take precedence over any allow you have previously granted.

Might want to test it first though chief.

(1): DO NOT USE the Everybody group, else you will not be able to create new users folders! For the same reason, avoid "Authenticated Users" or "Domain Users"